# C#/XAML Store App: accessing controls in FlipView.ItemTemplate

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

I've got a Flipview which has an ItemTemplate which contains a MediaElement and buttons for pause and play.  I need to be able to access the MediaElement based on the Clicked event on the buttons.  What is the best way to link my buttons to my MediaElement?  Most of the code examples I find on the internet apply to WPF and not Store Apps.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to use CommandParameters or some other type of XAML binding to pass the MediaElement control back to the event handler.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your MediaElement and buttons in a separate UserControl and put that control in your ItemTemplate. After that - it should be easy.

Comment: How would you then access that custom user control from the parent page?

Comment: Why would you want to do it?